# sharepoint 2013 custom site template not showing up on subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 subsite called 'projects' where all its projects are subsites that were created by a site template.

I wanted to make changes to the template so I created a new 'project' subsite using the template, made the changes and saved that subsite as a new site template.

Now, when I'm trying to create new project subsites I only see the old site template but can't see the new one.

I've checked the solution gallery and they are both appearing there in active state.

Any I ideas what went wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution: if I want to allow the use of site tamplates in subsites I need to enter their site settings and into 'Page layouts and site templates' and add the requested site template to the allowed list of site templates.

I can't believe the option was in front of me on the screen and I didn't see it...

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate the Publishing feature on the root and on the affected site.

Answer (score 0):

The Option for that setting is not there anymore. Don't know since when but I just had the same issue not being able to use a custom template for a new Site Collection.
-Template is present in solutions gallery
-Custom tab is not being displayed when I want to select a template for the newly created site
-In the site settings of the newly created site there is no Option "Page layouts and site templates" in the looks & feel section